# Saben para que sirve la propiedad de Accion de un Indicador en reportvierwer

Tags: c#, reportviewer

Alguien  para  que sirve la propiedad  **accion** de un **indicador**  de un **reportviewer**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: funciona de modo de hipervínculo.

Comment: puedes  ser un poco mas especifico

Comment: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiperenlace

Comment: pensaba que si yo le pongo una expresion  a la accion  el indicador  funcionaria dependiendo  a la expresion que  yo le puse